TV movie seen between 1970 to 1985 with lots of gray tones. Relationship develops between a boy and girl, girl drowns end of film nearby stream
There's a movie that I can't get out of my mind for years now.  I can't remember too many details unfortunately but it had an effect on me.  It was filmed in a lot of dark or gray tones.  There was a boy and girl as the focal characters.  Something happened and I believe it was the girl that ended up floating in the water near the end of the film.    The boy found her too late.  Reminiscent of Romeo and Juliet.  I believe the girl wore long black dresses/skirts, long black hair?  There was poverty.  Possibly depression era USA.  Not much to go on I know.
Saw it on TV so don't know if it was made for TV or rerun from cinema.
NOt sure if the boys name was Chauncy.

Welcome to the community. Plot-wise that's not a lot to go on. Any other plot details? Perhaps you remember how the plot develops their relationship. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Sounds like the TV version of Bridge to Terabithia... it was released to TV in 1985, and focuses on a friendship between a boy and girl, with the girl drowning in the end.

Key parts from the plot: ...the two friends invent a whole new world — Terabithi — and it comes to life through their eyes... Their teacher, Ms. Edmunds (Annette O'Toole), notices Jess's artistic skills and decides to take him on a field trip to an art museum. Jess has an unspoken crush on the teacher and does not want to share the trip with Leslie, so he goes to the museum without inviting her. When Jess returns home, his family is worried sick, as Jess's family neglected to listen when he said he was going, then tells him the horrific news: Leslie died after trying to cross the fallen tree over a rain-swollen creek... Jess feels overwhelming guilt for Leslie's death, thinking that it would not have happened had he invited Leslie along on his trip with Ms. Edmunds... Later, after crossing the creek, he hears a girl's voice calling for help and finds his little sister May Belle on the fallen tree trunk, frozen with terror after trying to follow him across. He rescues her, takes a minute to comfort her, then invites his sister to be the new princess...
A separate movie version from Disney was released in 2007.

Had no clue there was a TV version.
